# How to access application.context property from Play 2.2 application?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I would like to get access to application.context property (which is set in application.conf file) from within Play application. It's useful to know this property e.g. to pass it to JavaScript, so that addresses in script can be context independent.

I have looked in Scala API, but haven't found any way to obtain this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template file from which you call your Javascript code:

```
@import play.api.Play.current

<script type="application/javascript">
    var context = @play.api.Play.configuration.getString("application.context").getOrElse("")
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I did not understood that configuration option is taken by "name" and there is no getApplicationContext() accessor in Configuration object. This is the most exhaustive / descriptive answer (with example code), so I think it should be marked as solution (although I get to solution already after first comments). Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.configuration where `app` is
```

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/Application.html

Answer (score 0):

Get access from where?

`Play.configuration` should give you access to the Configuration object which provides a bunch of getters to retrieve app parameters.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Configuration

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider using Play's Javascript router, which is aware of the `application.context` property:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/ScalaJavascriptRouting